# Example for Client socket that try to connect to the server for 2 seconds

Tags: python, sockets, client, nonblocking

Someone can add to my Example under, the code that define the Client socket try to connect to the server for 2 seconds please ?
I read about that and i don't successful to do that, because of that i ask for an example.

Example:

Client:

```
import socket

TCP_IP = '127.0.0.1'

TCP_PORT = 7777

BUFFER_SIZE = 1024

MESSAGE = "Hello, World!"

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))

s.send(MESSAGE)

data = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)

s.close()

print "received data:", data
```

Server:

```
import socket

TCP_IP = '127.0.0.1'

TCP_PORT = 7777

BUFFER_SIZE = 20


s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

s.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))

s.listen(1)

conn, addr = s.accept()

print 'Connection address:', addr

while 1:

    data = conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)

    if not data: break

    print "received data:", data

    conn.send(data)

conn.close()
```

Thank you.

Comment: We need to see your server-side code as well. I ran your code, and the obvious result was a complaint about lack of server-side program.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having two separate python files, you can have a single file but put the server and client in separate threads. sys.stdout.write is used instead of print due some concurrency issue with print being buffered (it mixes strings).

```
import threading
import socket
import sys

class socket_server(threading.Thread):
    TCP_IP = "127.0.0.1"
    TCP_PORT = 7777
    BUFFER_SIZE = 20
    daemon = True

    def run(self):
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.bind((self.TCP_IP, self.TCP_PORT))
        s.listen(1)

        conn, addr = s.accept()
        (ip, port) = addr

        sys.stdout.write("%s connection address: IP %s on Port %d\n" % (self.__class__.__name__, ip, port))

        data = True
        while data:

            data = conn.recv(self.BUFFER_SIZE)

            if data:
                sys.stdout.write("%s received data: %s\n" % (self.__class__.__name__, data))
                send_data = data.upper()
                sys.stdout.write("%s sending data: %s\n" % (self.__class__.__name__, send_data))
                conn.send(send_data)

        conn.close()

class socket_client(threading.Thread):
    TCP_IP = "127.0.0.1"
    TCP_PORT = 7777
    BUFFER_SIZE = 1024
    TIMEOUT = 2.0
    MESSAGE = "Hello, World!"

    def run(self):
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.settimeout(self.TIMEOUT)
        s.connect((self.TCP_IP, self.TCP_PORT))
        sys.stdout.write("%s sending data: %s\n" % (self.__class__.__name__, self.MESSAGE))
        s.send(self.MESSAGE)

        data = s.recv(self.BUFFER_SIZE)

        s.close()

        if data:
            sys.stdout.write("%s received data: %s\n" % (self.__class__.__name__, data))

server = socket_server()
client = socket_client()

server.start()
client.start()
```

Comment: Yes, i am sure, you can try to fix it please ?

Comment: Can you clarify if you want it to try to connect for 2 seconds or connect and hold the connection for 2 seconds ?

Comment: I want to try to connect for 2 seconds .

Comment: If that's the case, then it should work according to http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.settimeout. And it does for me. Possibly there are other issues?

Comment: Hmm, i don't know, it's strange.
What can i do ?

Comment: What Operating System and version of Python are you running?

Comment: I have windows 8 and Python 2.7

Comment: So its failing to connect? It could be a firewall blocking ports.